# Notation of algebraic closure of set

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $T$ be a transcendental basis of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q.$

**Definition**.  $\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ denotes an algebraic closure of $\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ in $\Bbb R$, that is, $\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$ is the set of $x\in\Bbb R$ that are algebraic over $\Bbb Q(S).$ I think, My question is just notation question

> Is the correct notation for closure $\overline{\Bbb Q(S)}$, $\overline{\Bbb Q}(S)$, or $\text{alg}(S)$?

> Let $x\in\Bbb R$, then there exists $S\subset T$ such that $x\in\bar{\Bbb Q}(S)$? $S$ can be either finit or infinite? Right?

Comment: I think $\overline{\Bbb Q(S)}=\overline{\Bbb Q}(S)$ should be a theorem, but it's probably false

Comment: I think none of these notations are appropriate. In each case there is no indication that your new field has anything to do with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In each case respectively I would say these mean (i) an alg. clos. of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ (inside e.g., $\mathbb{C}$ if $S \subset \mathbb{R}$) (ii) the smallest field containing $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $S$ (inside $\mathbb{C}$ under the same conditions) (iii) I don't really know. In each case this object is not contained in $\mathbb{R}$ so certaianly that should be in the notation

Comment: Ihf, could you please explain

Comment: $\overline{\Bbb Q}(\pi)$ is the set of rational expressions in $\pi$ with algebraic coefficients and so does not contain $\sqrt\pi$, which is algebraic over $\Bbb Q(\pi)$.

Comment: Ihf, I think , my problem was that I don't know a reference that  uses this notation. Do you know a book or perhaps a paper that introduce this notation ? Thank you

Comment: Ihf, In case , you do not know such  a reference, so you can give the exact definition for $\overline{\Bbb Q}(S)$ . This will help as well. Thank you

Comment: egreg, Do you have an idea what is the correct notations?